# I have mtcars inbuilt data set in R and I want categorocal data but all my columns are numeric. How too find categorical

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, data-science

I have mtcars inbuilt data set in R and I want categorical data but all my columns are numeric.

Below is the structure of "mtcars" inbuilt data set. I want to find the categorical data columns.

```
 str(Mt_cars_data)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
```

Could you help me in finding and converting them to categorical variables.

Comment: You could make a good start on this by typing `help(mtcars)` and reading the descriptions of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the columns of class `"factor"` run

```
i <- sapply(mtcars, is.factor)
names(mtcars)[i]
#character(0)
```

This means that none of the columns is a factor column.

There are also similar functions for classes `"logical"`, `"integer"`, `"numeric"`, `"character"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deduce categorical variables (factors) by inspection if they are not explicitly defined.  You can convert numeric as well as character columns to factors by using the `as.factor`function.  E.g.:

```
cars <- mtcars
cars$cyl <- as.factor(cars$cyl)
```

Note that the `unique` function can help identify the columns that may be factors.  e.g.

```
uniques <- lapply(cars, unique)
```

That will give you a list of the unique values of each column variable.  By inspection of the elements of the `uniques` list you can determine which variables could probably be converted to factors.